# How to add parts of an image to an ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, 2d

For homework I am trying to add a sprite sheet to a 2D ArrayList for a simple card game. I want to be able to have it like you would in a normal 2D array only with the dynamic ability of the array list since I will have to remove cards that are already drawn.

I am using a number generator that will generate numbers between the first and last indexes (0 - 51) inclusive and it will show a card up on the screen when the user clicks the draw card button. Then it will allow another user or an AI to draw a card and it will determine who has the highest card and declare that person the winner of that round, remove both drawn cards and repeat the cycle until 26 turns have been surpassed then the program will tally up all round wins and the player with the most round wins wins the game overall.

My question is: How can I divide my one sprite sheet into 52 sections and add that to my ArrayList?

This is what I have so far. I know it doesn't work yet, but I'm not entirely sure if I'm on the right track.

```
//private ImageIcon[][] cards = new ImageIcon[4][13];
private BufferedImage img;  
private final int _WIDTH = 74;
private final int _HEIGHT = 94;

public CardGame1(ImageIcon[][] cards){
    try{
        img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(
                "classic-playing-cards.png"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int r = 0; r < cards.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < cards[r].length; c++){
            cards[r][c] = new ImageIcon(img.getSubimage(c * _WIDTH, 
                    r * _HEIGHT, _WIDTH, _HEIGHT));
        }
    }

}
```

Some one told me to put the ArrayList in another class so here it is:

```
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private Random rand;
private JButton drawCard;
private JLabel card;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<CardGame1>> _cardObj 
= new ArrayList<ArrayList<CardGame1>>();

public CardGameGUI(){
    gameBoard();
}

public void gameBoard(){
    frame = new JFrame("Card Game");
    panel = new JPanel();
    frame.setSize(600, 500);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    drawCard = new JButton("Draw Card!");
    drawCard.setSize(100, 50);
    panel.add(drawCard);
    drawCard.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I cannot follow your though process. Some code / e.g. would help.

Answer (score 0):

These links that should solve your problem

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#copyData-java.awt.image.WritableRaster-

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.awt.image.WritableRaster